# Installing RVM: getting error "There was an error(23)."

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I am trying to install Ruby Version Manager (RVM) without success.
How to get through this error I am getting?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-20:/tmp$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p484.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p484 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p484, this may take a while depending on your connection...
Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-1.9.3-p484.tar.bz2.part: Permission
Warning: denied
  0 9806k    0  1002    0     0  22905      0  0:07:18 --:--:--  0:07:18 23302
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1002)
There was an error(23).
Checking fallback: http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p484.tar.bz2
Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-1.9.3-p484.tar.bz2.part: Permission
Warning: denied
  0 9806k    0  1167    0     0   4300      0  0:38:55 --:--:--  0:38:55  4290
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1167)
There was an error(23).
Failed download
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-20:/tmp$
```

Comment: Try going to this website and see if you can download the tar file from there: http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p484.tar.bz2

Comment: It looks like it's trying to download the file to a directory you don't have permission to write to. Use the `--debug` flag (i.e. `rvm --debug install ...`) to get more verbose output and update your question.

Comment: hey man, accept answer. Solution is working properly!

Answer (score 151):

Your RVM is installed in `/usr/local/rvm` - it's often called system installation, this requires that your user `ubuntu` will be added to `rvm` group:

```
rvm group add rvm "$USER"
```

yes use `$USER` it will be replaced by your shell with your user name

then log out and log in, ensure with:

```
id
```

that your user is in `rvm` group,

finally just in case update permissions for RVM:

```
rvm fix-permissions
```

Comment: Fixed problem for me. Thank you!

Comment: Cheers, though I had to restart the computer not just logout.

Comment: You can also run `su - $USER` in order to update your user's rights, without logging out and in again. Then `id` should list you as part of the rvm group

Comment: Hi. I'm using Linux Mint and had the same problem, tryied this solution and didn't work, I had to run `sudo chown -R $USER:rvm /usr/share/rvm/.` 

BTW, the installation path of rvm is now `/usr/share/rvm`  as stated in the Ubuntu installation here: https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @mpasis might not work if you're installing `rvm` using [ubuntu_rvm](https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm) as by default because of `copy+paste` it'll be installed as `root`.
Try installing `rvm` with without `sudo` or with `curl` as explained on [rvm.io](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).